# The named parameter 'title' isn't defined.Try correcting the name with the name 'title'.dart

Tags: flutter, dart

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_pages[_selectedPageIndex]['title']),
      ),
      drawer: MainDrawer(),
      body: _pages[_selectedPageIndex]['page'],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: _selectPage,
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        currentIndex: _selectedPageIndex,
        // type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,


    items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                icon: Icon(Icons.category),
                title: Text('Categories'),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                icon: Icon(Icons.star),
                title: Text('Favorites'),
              ),
```

I'm just learning Flutter and I got such an error in

```
[(title: Text('Categories')& title: Text('Favorites')]
```

but I entered the same commands as the video I watched, what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like an old video, `title` is now deprecated, use `label` property instead, and just give it a String property, ex: 'Categories', 'Favorites', ...

https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/bottom-navigation-title-to-label